# What does "rendering" mean (backbone.js)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So far I've been working only with HTML, CSS, some JavaScript and jQuery - nothing more. Recently at work I had to start dealing with backbone.js and I'm pretty lost.

What exactly does "rendering" mean? I keep finding answers to "when to render", "how to render" etc. etc. but no explanation of the term (I'm not a native English speaker).

Comment: This will probably help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)

Comment: I upvoted too fast thinking it leads to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine
which is rather a different kind of rendering? Anyway,.I took a look at that before but I wouldn't mind a more straight forward explanation. For example: to learn something I need to see the purpouse of it, so far I see it as a more difficult way of making something that can be done in a more simple way. For sure there are pro's, but what are they? What is rendering and why using it?

Comment: The simple explanation is that rendering is the process of displaying something on a screen. If one wishes the user to see a visual representation of some result in a program, it must be rendered in some form or fashion be it text, graphics, etc. It isn't so much a question of pros and cons, but simple necessity. That is to say, one either needs to render or one does not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a word in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Generally it means to create a final result from a given model/template. For example if you have a template

```
<body>{{my_var}}</body>
```

Then you can render it with `my_var=1`. The result will be

```
<body>1</body>
```

This obviously depends on templating engine (it has to recognize that `{{my_var}}` has to be replaced by `1`, in particular it has to know that `{{` and `}}` are special chars). This can be easily generalized to more complicated structures like views.

Comment: Ok, any way to explain this to someone whose javascript knowledge is limited to simple if's and for loop's?

Comment: @user3691280 I'm not sure what else do you want me to explain? What is it that you still don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering means sending final output to browser or sending view to browser in MVC pattern.